# Org Mode iCalendar export non-unique UID generation

Tags: emacs, icalendar, emacs23, org-mode

I am using Emacs 23.2 and I am using `org-mode` to keep track of my tasks. I have quite a list of tasks that I have made up as events by mentioning the time period and adding the `SCHEDULED` tag for the tasks.

When I export the task to the iCalendar file, using the <kbd>C-c C-e i</kbd> command, I get the `.ics` file but many of the tasks have the same UID even though the date and the time stamp mentioned are different. Why is this so? Is there a way I can generate unique UIDs in `org-mode`?

I tried customizing the UID format variable to `%s%temacs` and some other list of format specifiers in the customization but it does not seem to work.

Has anyone faced this kind of a problem?

Thanks
Shyam

Comment: AFAICT, this is no longer a problem (at least, I cannot reproduce it). If it is resolved, can you add an answer and mark it solved?